# Solving a polynomial equation for $x$ when one solution is given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

the issue I'm having is this problem:

If $x=2$ is one of the solutions to 
$x^3-6x^2+13x=10$, then find the other solutions.

It says the other solutions are:

$x = 2+i$ and $x = 2-i$.

Can anyone show me how those are the solutions? This is really bothersome and confusing, thank you!

Comment: Hint: divide the polynomial by $x-2$ since you know it's a factor.

Comment: One way to do that is to perform synthetic division

Comment: hint: $$\begin{align}
x^3-6x^2+13x-10 &= (x^3-2x^2)-4x^2+13x-10\\
&= (x^3-2x^2)+(-4x^2+8x)+(5x-10)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have showed you how to get the answer with full detailed working.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this was very helpful! Thank you very much for this response. Very nice handwriting by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if $x=a$ is a solution, then $(x-a)$ is a factor of the polynomial so you can divide it out. In your case $x=2$ is a solution so you should divide the polynomial by a factor of $(x-2)$.

$$ \frac{x^3-6x^2+13x-10}{x-2} = 0 $$
which gives you
$$ x^2-4x+5=0 \quad\text{for}\, x\neq2$$
use the quadratic formula
$$ \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{-4}}{2} = 2 \,\pm\,\sqrt{-1} $$
$$ x = 2 \pm i $$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}{lllllll}
&&&+x^2&-4x&+5\\
\\
x&-2&&+x^3&-6x^2&+13x&-10\\
&&&+x^3&-2x^2\\
\\
&&&&-4x^2&+13x\\
&&&&-4x^2&+8x\\
\\
&&&&&+5x&-10\\
&&&&&+5x&-10
\end{array}$

The quotient $x^2-4x+5$
is the LHS of the equation you need to solve. 0 is the RHS.